# JDK 7 doesn't want to upgrade

Tags: java

I downloaded and installed perfectly the new JDK release (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), but whenever I am about to start a new project in NetBeans, the program only offers the "JDK 1.7" version, so I am not sure if it has been upgraded correctly or not.

Comment: I think you installed newer version you didn't upgrade it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the new JDK environment manually to NetBeans after the newr JDK installation!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the JDK packaged with NetBeans from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html).